# Apex trigger running twice

Tags: apex, trigger, account

For the Account object, we have two user defined fields: User_type__c and Account_Type__c.  On the entry screen User_type__c is a dropdown box where the user selects a value.  Upon clicking save, the value from User_type__c is used to lookup a table on record creation or any time User_type__c is changed and get the data for Account_Type__c.  The AccountUpdate trigger should then fire to send the record to our servers.  Apparently the code below is sending the record twice when the record is created...once with a blank TypeCode followed by a populated TypeCode.  The trigger code is:

```
trigger AccountUpdate on Account (after insert, after update) {
    String buildMessage;
    for(Account a:Trigger.new){
        if (a.RecordTypeId == '0125Y000001GTK4QAO')    //business accounts only
        {    
            buildMessage = '{';    
            buildMessage = buildMessage + '"BillingCity": "' + a.BillingCity + '"'; 
            buildMessage = buildMessage + ', "BillingPostalCode":' + '"' + a.BillingPostalCode + '"';
            buildMessage = buildMessage + ', "BillingState":' + '"' + a.BillingState + '"';
            buildMessage = buildMessage + ', "BillingStreet":' + '"' + a.BillingStreet + '"';
            buildMessage = buildMessage + ', "Phone":' + '"' + a.Phone + '"';
            buildMessage = buildMessage + ', "County":' + '"' + a.County__c + '"';
            buildMessage = buildMessage + ', "Facility_c":' + '"' + a.Facility__c + '"';
            buildMessage = buildMessage + ', "Name":' + '"' + a.Name + '"';
            buildMessage = buildMessage + ', "TypeCode":' + '"' + a.Account_Type__c + '"';            
            buildMessage = buildMessage + ', "Level6":' + '"' + a.Level_6__c + '"';
            buildMessage = buildMessage + ', "RecordId":' + '"' + a.Id + '"';            
            buildMessage = buildMessage + '}';
            AccountDestinationCallout.putDestination(buildMessage);    
    }   
}
```

The more confusing thing is, if I remove the statement

```
buildMessage = buildMessage + ', "TypeCode":' + '"' + a.Account_Type__c + '"';
```

the record is sent one time.   This does not happen if it is an update, it only send twice if the record is added.

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening and how I can get the above trigger to only send the record one time with the TypeCode statement included?

Update:

Would this be the correct syntax to check if the record is a certain record type and a particular field is not null:

```
if (a.RecordTypeId == '0125Y000001GTK4QAO' && a.Account_Type__c != 'null')
```

I also tried this, but neither seems to bypass correctly:

```
if (a.RecordTypeId == '0125Y000001GTK4QAO' && a.Account_Type__c != null)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135051/discussion-on-question-by-sfapexuser-apex-trigger-running-twice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a process builder or flow that performs the type update. This explains why the trigger is firing twice, and the two API calls. Either move the field update logic into a Before Save flow, or check if TypeCode is null before making the API call.

Comment: The type update was not created by me.  But I think I understand what you are saying.  I'll have to contact the person who created it.  I dont think checking if it is null would work since the value can be blank.

Comment: So why would it fire twice only when I am referencing the field?  If I take that one statement out it will only send once.

Comment: @SFApexUser The flow is conditional, so it only fires if the field value actually changes. I suspect you're misinterpreting what's going on. Changing the code won't change how many times the trigger itself fires.

Comment: I am first to admit I would misinterpret this. It just seems confusing that by removing that one line it runs without an issue.  Anyway, I am now checking for if the field is 'null' and it looks like it is working correctly.  Thank you for your time - I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: I was mistaken...the null check, as shown above is not bypassing the send.